# using filter to exclude entries in df found in a separate list

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have information from CT scans done on specific pigs. I want to exclude certain cases that don't meet my inclusion criteria (were too old at the time of the scan).

I'm watching how the airways react to a drug, so i have multiple scans over time looking at things like airway area, diameter, etc. So i have several hundred observations per pig with and without treatment.

I have 17 pigs:

```
df %>% distinct(pig)
# A tibble: 17 × 1
   pig   
   <fct> 
 1 29-10 
 2 29-9  
 3 31-1  
 4 31-3  
 5 29-1  
 6 29-2  
 7 29-5  
 8 29-4  
 9 29-6  
10 100-1 
11 100-3 
12 107-1 
13 107-11
14 107-2 
15 107-3 
16 107-4 
17 107-5
```

I want to filter out the following pigs because they were too old when they were scanned:

`29-1, 29-2, 29-4, 29-5,29-6`

I can filter individually:

```
df %>% 
  filter(pig != "29-1", 
         pig != "29-2", 
         pig != "29-4", 
         pig ! ="29-5", 
         pig != "29-6")
```

I'd prefer to make a list of excluded pigs. I can re-use for various analysis, the opposite of:

```
excluded <- c("29-1", "29-2", "29-4", "29-5", "29-6") 

df%>% 
  filter(pig %in% excluded) %>% 
  distinct(pig)
```

I've tried using the ! operator but can't seem to get the syntax to work. Should be straightforward but can't seem to get it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `!` operator:

`df %>% filter(!(pig %in% excluded))`